# wraping of webelement in my program for selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

After creating few wrappers for selenium webdriver framework. i'm trying to create/invoke the driver object for webelement. its giving the NPE .kindly let me out here..

code tried..

```
@Override
    public WebElement findElementbyId(By el) {
        element = driver.findElement(By.id("el"));
        return element;
    }
```

i want to access webelement like

```
element.findById("email");
```

kindly share my the snippet on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public WebElement findElementbyId(By el) {
    element = driver.findElement(By.id("el"));
    return element;
}
```

is incorrect, as you can see that you actually are not using the parameter within your findElement.

try using:

```
@Override
public WebElement findElementbyId(String id) {
    element = driver.findElement(By.id(id));
    return element;
}
```

Comment: how to create generic method for isDisplayed()?  `public static boolean isDisplayed(WebDriver driver, String locatorType, String str) {
  switch (locatorType) {
  case "id":
   driver.findElement(By.id(str)).isDisplayed();

  default:
   break;
  }
  return false;

 }`